# Value of json data using javascript

Tags: javascript, json

Could some one help me how to retrieve the value of tags(i want the value M from below) in the below json output using javascript.
i got the value if id using this jsonData["items"][i].id; but tags value M not bale to retrieve.

```
{
  "items": [

    {
      "id": 2789434725001,
      "name": "La récolte de maïs peut-elle impacter les cours ?",
      "shortDescription": "31/10/2013\rAu programme : un point sur les récoltes de maïs, l'influence de la production d'huile de palme en provenance de Malaisie, les conséquences de la hausse probable du taux de TVA sur les engrais.",
      "tags": [
        "jt",
        "youtube",
        "M"
      ],
      "thumbnailURL": "http://brightcove.vo.llnwd.net/d21/unsecured/media/585058619001/201310/2640/585058619001_2789497487001_th-52727bebe4b03283b8406026-1592194012001.jpg?pubId=585058619001"
    },

    {
      "id": 2752758713001,
      "name": "Impact sur le marché mondial de l'accord concernant le budget américain",
      "shortDescription": "18/10/2013\rAu sommaire : l'impact sur les marchés agricoles de l'accord concernant le budget américain, un point sur le développement des cultures en Amérique du Sud et sur le changement de tendance sur le marché des orges.",
      "tags": [
        "jt",
        "youtube",
        "M"
      ],
      "thumbnailURL": "http://brightcove.vo.llnwd.net/d21/unsecured/media/585058619001/201310/911/585058619001_2752793938001_th-52613c28e4b0ebd227209755-782203294001.jpg?pubId=585058619001"
    },

   ],
  "page_number": 0,
  "page_size": 10,
  "total_count": 245
}
```

Comment: There is no value for 'M', it is merely listed in a tags array

Comment: Ive seen a few questions from YouTube that use an 'm' value and have a JSON response that contains it... I think if you want 'm' for a video you need different data from YouTube

Comment: your JSON has Parse error on line 24:
...    },            ],    "page_number"
---------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['  http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
var tags = jsonData["items"][i].tags;
var m = tags[tags.length-1];
```

or

```
var m = jsonData["items"][i].tags[2];
```

If you want to know if "M" is among the tags, you may do

```
var hasM = jsonData["items"][i].tags.indexOf("M")>=0;
```

Comment: Hi its throwing me error "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined".

Comment: @user1442351 before reading `m`, you might want to check `tags` is defined.

Comment: hi check this url[link](http://api.brightcove.com/services/library?command=find_all_videos&page_size=10&video_fields=id%2Cname%2CshortDescription%2Ctags%2CthumbnailURL&media_delivery=default&sort_by=PUBLISH_DATE&sort_order=DESC&page_number=0&get_item_count=true&callback=BCL.onSearchResponse&token=UNMmXGNTgCgabuMF-t6qcWANkUriYnia2OC4OsxlWqx9flj-jfzntw..)